# Overriding scale in Konva shapes

Tags: konvajs

Setting scale on Stage also changes the scale in Layer subtree children of the Stage (via inheritance?). 
Is an event fired by Konva when Stage scale is set? Because I want to override scale setting in a shape contained in a Layer belonging to the stage (so as not to scale too small or too large in the shape).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
stage.on('scaleXChange scaleYChange', () => {
   console.log('scale is changed');
});
```

But basically, you are changing the scale of the stage somewhere in your code.
So in that place, you can just apply a new scale to the internal shapes.

Comment: Awesome to know; does that work for Shape type as well (it's not working for me)?

Comment: it would be handy to change scale on Stage and emit an event, such that for child nodes the change can be intercepted and handled differently (THREE.js emits events within its scene trees in such scenarios).